# Code does not recover correctly - CS50 Week4 Recover Problem

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, computer-science, cs50

Does somebody has any ideas why code is not working properly? It outputs all the 50 recovered images in proper names, but I still got this:

```
:) recover.c exists.
:) recover.c compiles.
:) handles lack of forensic image
:( recovers 000.jpg correctly
    000.jpg not found
:( recovers middle images correctly
    001.jpg not found
:( recovers 049.jpg correctly
    049.jpg not found
:| program is free of memory errors
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

My code is

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *card_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (card_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot read correctly the file\n");
        return 2;
    }

    const int BLOCK_SIZE = 512;
    BYTE buffer [BLOCK_SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    FILE *output = NULL;

    while (fread(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, card_file) == BLOCK_SIZE)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {

            char filename[8];
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", i);

            output = fopen(filename, "w");
            fwrite(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, output);

            ++i;
            fclose(output);
        }
    }

    fclose(card_file);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The recovered images will be greater than 512 bytes. You need to leave the file open after you write the header and continue to write to the same file until you find another header. Then close the existing file, open the next, and keep going. You should also open the files in binary mode `"rb"` and `"wb"` both to show intent and to work correctly on Windows machines.

Comment: `while (fread(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, card_file) == BLOCK_SIZE)` is in error. The  item `size` is `BLOCK_SIZE` and the `count` is `1`, so you won't get `BLOCK_SIZE` items read. On success you'll get `1`. That is why none of the other files are found.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thank you, I have already figured it out at night, but thanks for brief explanation